# Dll создания представления (C#/wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть небольшой проект [git repository](https://github.com/TomDugger/NTW.Presentation), который позволяет формировать шаблоны wpf для объектов.

Есть dll которая позволяет формировать Ui из объектов.

Застопорился на формировании Ui для объекта типа Dictionary.

Может подскажете как лучше организовать Ui добавления нового элемента?

Вкратце, через рифлексию собирается информация о типе, его свойствах и атрибутах. Далее на основе собранной информации формируется DataTemplate. Если требуется, объект оборачивается в специальную viewModel, как это происходит со свойством типа Dictionary. ViewModel формирует привязку к свойству и предоставляет небольшой функционал для работы с этим свойством. Отображение данных настроил, но с добавлением проблема. Так как свойство типа Dictionary имеет два параметра типа Generic. В этом и вся загвоздка. Как создать ключ типа Generic да еще и из UI.

Распишу более подробно. Есть класс:

```
public class MyPresentation : Presentation
{
    public Dictionary<int, PresentationItem> dictionary { get; set; }
}
```

после запуска приложения генератор сформируется Ui для свойства dictionary:

[image: Ui]

Теперь хочу добавить возможность добавления нового элемента в Dictionary. не могу придумать как организовать панель добавления так как не знаю к какому типу будет относится TKey и как его отображать в ComboBox.

Comment: Так в чем суть проблемы? Что не получается?

Comment: Пройдите [тур](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour), чтобы понять какие вопросы можно задавать на StackOverflow. Ваш вопрос слишком широк для формата вопрос-ответ.

Comment: Собственно вопрос в самом проекте. Есть dll которая позволяет формировать Ui из объектов. Застопорился на формирование Ui для объекта типа Dictionary. Может подскажете как лучше организовать Ui добавления нового элемента/

Comment: Благодарю за исправления

Comment: @TomDugger, добавь больше информации про то, как это сейчас происходит и что бы ты хотел поменять

Comment: Чтобы отредактировать вопрос и добавить в него нужную информацию используй кнопку [edit]

Comment: Увы но нет. Не имеется в виду создание объекта. Тут скорей требуется Ui, который позволит добавить новый элемент в Dictionary.

Comment: _В этом и вся загвоздка. **Как создать ключ типа Generic** да еще и из UI._

Comment: _не могу придумать как организовать панель добавления так как не знаю к какому типу будет относится TKey и как его отображать в ComboBox._ - очевидно, что в общем виде задача нерешаема, так как не все типы могут быть сериализованы во что-то

Comment: Во всех остальных случаях, можно применять тот же самый подход, что ты сейчас используешь для отображения значения

Comment: И еще раз: если ты не считаешь свой вопрос дубликатом, не стоило соглашаться с тем, что это дубликат, а стоило просто добавить больше информации, которая бы показала, что это действительно не дубликат

Comment: Хорошо, Спасибо за помощь. Буду иметь в виду

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Автор, если тебе нужно понять, что объект является `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` и получить типы его параметров, то ты можешь это сделать вот так:

```
Boolean IsDictionary(Object obj, out Type keyType, out Type valueType)
{
    keyType = null;
    valueType = null

    Type type = obj.GetType();
    if (!type.IsGenericType || type.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
        return false;

    Type genericType = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    if (genericType  != typeof(Dictionary<,>)
        return false;

    Type[] genericArguments = type.GetGenericArguments();
    keyType = genericArguments[0];
    valueType = genericArguments[1];

    return true;
}
```

Конструировать сам `Dictionary`, как я понял из вопроса, тебе не нужно. Только его элементы. Но если вдруг это необходимо, то зная его тип, ты можешь получить его вызовом метода `GetConstructor`. Если же тип тебе неизвестен, но ты знаешь типы ключа и значения, то тебе поможет метод `MakeGenericType`, который ты должен вызвать на GenericTypeDefinition - в твоём случае так: `typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(...)`

**Отвечая на детализированный вопрос автора:**
Тебе поможет [`DataTemplateSelector`](http://csharpcoding.org/dinamicheskij-vybor-shablona/). Определи шаблон для каждого типа, и используй его для выбора нужного. Также ты можешь генерировать нужные тебе шаблоны на лету в том же `DataTemplateSelector`.

Comment: Все же не то. Приму как ответ.

Comment: @TomDugger, если ответ не отвечает на вопрос , не стоит его принимать. Стоит отредактировать вопрос, чтобы стало ясно, что именно ты хочешь. Добавить больше подробностей, возможно пример твоего кода

Comment: @TomDugger обновли ответ с учётом новых подробностей.

Comment: DataTemplateSelector не совсем подходит. В самом начале запуска приложения метод обрабатывает связанные классы и формирует для них шаблоны. Мы же не можем менять тип свойства на лету, следовательно если свойства типа int то оно не может превратится в string. В любом случае перед отображением окна все требуемые шаблоны добавлены в ресурсы. Мне нужна была всего лишь подсказка, как лучше организовать панель добавления исходя из пары требуемых значений словаря, при этом в словаре значение ключа не повторяется.

Comment: @TomDugger нет, к сожалению, всё ещё не понимаю проблемы. Ты спрашиваешь - как отобразить элемент в ComboBox. Я отвечаю - повесь на него DataTemplateSelector. Если ты не можешь предусмотреть все возможные типы ключей, то и отобразить ты их сможешь только каким-то обобщенным правилом, например вызовом ToString() или какого-нибудь публичного свойства этого ключа. Если возможные ключи всё-таки ограничены, но вариант с селектором не подходит, подведи их под общий интерфейс, пусть предоставляю средства форматирования или шаблоны. В общем, попробуй ещё детальнее объяснить проблему. Нарисуй что ли?

Comment: @Lunar Whisper comboBox совсем ни причем. В любом случай в нем все элементы будут отображаться методом ToString(), либо специальным шаблоном, который будет предопределен. Если свойство типа List<string>, то проблем с добавлением нового элемента нет - через  активатор создаться новый экземпляра строки и запишется в данное свойство. Тут панель ввода не нужна. Со свойством типа Dictionaty<string, string> будет сложнее. Потребуется специальная панель для ввода как минимум ключа. Вот и не могу придумать как создать эту панель при добавлении нового элемента в словарь.

Comment: @Lunar Whisper библиотека изначально разрабатывается для того что бы избавится от формирования разметки xaml.

Comment: @TomDugger и что мешает использовать темплейты и селекторы из кода? Не обязательно делать это в xaml.

Comment: @Lunar Whisper после запуска приложения все типы знают в каком виде им отображаться (т.е. обладают собственным шаблоном), Нет смысла использовать селектор так как система наверняка знает какой шаблон применять и для какого свойства. И все же вернусь к началу. Нужно придумать специальную панель которая сможет сформировать новый элемент свойство типа Dictionary, либо алгоритм автоматической генерации новых элементов для словаря с последующим добавлением в свойство.

Comment: Вопрос решен. Хешсуммы двух однотипных объектов не совпадают следовательно, если тип TKey относится к обычным типам то будет производится автоматическое формирование значения (в зависимости от типа), в противном случая создается новый объект типа TKey и он со сто процентной уверенности и содержится в словаре.

Comment: @TomDugger это парадоксально, но даже к тому моменту, когда ты сам нашёл решение, ни я, ни (подозреваю) все остальные, так и не поняли ни задачу, ни проблему, ни решение.

И нет, ты не прав насчёт хэшсуммы. Не знаю, что ты под ней подоразумеваешь, но если речь о GetHashCode, то это только `2^32 - 1` уникальных значений. Благодаря [парадоксу дней рождений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81_%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) коллизия случится гораздо раньше.

Comment: @ Lunar Whisper, я выкладывал ссылку на github, где есть полный код, что и как работает. Я уже не знаю как подробнее описать что и как работает.